# res/layout for tablets 7", 8", 10"

Tags: android, layout, tablet

How can I separate layout folders for tablet 7", tablet 8" and tablet 10" if I need one folder for general layouts (7", 8", 10") and folder for unique 7" layouts?
Thank you!

Comment: Android doesn't support selection based on physical screen size. Though, you may want to read [this blog regarding that](http://android-developers.blogspot.sg/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html).

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can seperatly make this below folders inside resources Folder,

```
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets

res/layout-sw600dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets // for Landscape mode
res/layout-sw720dp-land/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets // for Landscape mode
```

For different Purpose.

Comment: How do I discern 7" and 8"?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html In this hyperlink check Description for Table 2 & below it. Hope this help...